# UITableView controller class does not recognize SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate

Tags: uitableview

I an building an in app store
Created a UITableViewController. Unfortunately it does no allow adding to the class: SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate:

import UIKit
import StoreKit

class StoreTableViewController: UITableViewController, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate

{

```
var product: SKProduct!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Start an observer
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
```

}

The remark: cannot invoke addTransactionObserver with an argument list of type UITableViewController

Comment: It tuns out that the controller should be SKStoreProductViewController and not UITableViewController

Comment: It does after almost the entire code is ready